# Python regex find strings that only contain space

Tags: python, regex

I want to use regex in Python to find the string(s) which is empty or only contain space.

```
"    "  - True
" "     - True
""      - True
"  1  " - False
```

How to do it via regex?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall` and anchor the search from the start of the string (`^`) and end of the string (`$`):

```
import re
strings = ['    ', ' ', '', '  1  ']
results = [i for i in strings if re.findall('^\s*$', i)]
```

Output:

```
['    ', ' ', '']
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Pleases see my recent edit.

Comment: Yes, a 1,000,000th dupe, I have seen it before a lot of times.